# Which regular expression to use to extract some words from an HTML text?

Tags: regex

I am having a hard time building a regular expression to grab some words from a HTML text.

Let's say I have the following :

`<p style="padding-left :12px">SOME_TEXT_I_WANT</p><p>SOME_OTHER_TEXT</p>`

*SOME_TEXT_I_WANT* and *SOME_OTHER_TEXT* can be either a bunch of words like "SOME RANDOM TEXT" or HTML text like "`<strong>SOME BOLD TEXT</strong>`"

My goal is to extract those texts with one regex.

Comment: What if the second part is `<p>some text<p>and some other text</p> and yet more text</p>`? Regexps and HTML are always a brittle combination.

Comment: Before the haters start up, there is a movement concerning html and RE. RE CAN parse simple html to a degree and can do it well.  However, like Piskvor says (and well might I add), "it is brittle"; doable but be careful of your source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which language do you intend to use? Does a HTML parser exist for this language? If yes, **consider using a parser**.

However, if this is a "one-off", you *may* be able to get through with something along the lines of:

```
#<p[^>]*>(.*?)</p>#
```

The above has certain limitations, most notably it does not match `<p data-something="a > b">...</p>` nor nested `<p>`s. (I am not able to tell whether the mark-up you're trying to parse actually allows nested `<p>`s—just informing you on possible pitfalls.)

Comment: Indeed. This can work for **very simple** HTML-like strings; using regexps for extracting data from HTML is a nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: @Piskvor Exactly. One should always be very certain that the input is actually suited for expression-based matching before jumping on the RegExp band-wagon.

Comment: This is working great ! It was quite obvious but I was looking for a difficult thing... And don't worry, this is not intended to parse large web pages but only some text from a personnal web app.

Comment: @Anth0 In that case you should be fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP:

```
$html = "<p>some text here</p>"
preg_replace("/<.+?>/","", $html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex. If you ask why, there is a very popular [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) that describes what can happen if you try to use regex for parsing HTML.

Use your language's HTML or XML parser and extract what you need using existing functionality.